# Solve $y'(t) + 6y(t) = 2x(t)$ for impulse response using differential method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\dfrac{dy}{dt} + 6y(t) = 2x(t)$  $\to$ $\dfrac{dh}{dt} + 6\delta(t) = 2\delta(t)$

zero initial conditions

solving for roots

$e^{st}(s+6)=0$

$s= -6 \to  h=C_1e^{-6t}$

I want to solve for $C_1$

Is it $h(0)=$ the other side of the equation at t=0

in this case  $2\delta(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

To solve $y'+6y=2x$, note that 
$$(\mathrm e^{6t}y(t))'=\mathrm e^{6t}(y'(t)+6y(t)),$$ hence 
$$
\mathrm e^{6t}y(t)=y(0)+2\int_0^t\mathrm e^{6s}x(s)\mathrm ds,
$$
and finally,
$$
y(t)=y(0)\mathrm e^{-6t}+2\mathrm e^{-6t}\int_0^t\mathrm e^{6s}x(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
The rest depends on $x$. Let me guess that $x=\delta$ means that
$$
2\int_0^t\mathrm e^{6s}x(s)\mathrm ds=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}-1&\text{if}&t\lt0,\\1&\text{if}&t\gt0,\end{array}\right.
$$
then,
$$
y(t)=\mathrm e^{-6t}(y(0)+\mathrm{sgn}(t)).
$$

Comment: I think I get it. It is just reverse chain rule. The delta function is not defined that way and uses different limits of integration.  thanks.

Comment: "The delta function is not defined that way and uses different limits of integration" I am pretty curious to see how your definition of delta does not entail the consequences I used. Please feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: The integral condition in your comment is entirely compatible with the identity used in my answer, actually it implies it if one adds the symmetry condition that $$\int_{-a}^ax(t)\delta(t)\mathrm dt=2\int_0^ax(t)\delta(t)dt.$$.